# Reference for "it" in the sentence

Tags: reference

In the following paragraph, the reference of "it" in the last sentence is not clear to me. Is it the "Fallen Angel" film? Its style? or "technology"?

> In Fallen Angels, images accumulate as bits and pieces of a thoroughly
> imagined whole. We are shown: characters moving about, performing
> tasks, going through rituals of work and leisure and heartbreak
> against the backdrop of a neon-lit city at night (the underworld of
> Hong Kong). And while we may recognize objects or places (“that’s a
> subway” or “this is a fast food shop”), the style in which they are
> shown, treated by the camera, dislocates them from the plastic,
> sensate world. It evokes instead, and powerfully, compromising
> nothing, a state of the world known all too well by anyone who has
> ever had a cell phone ring during a night at the movies: time and
> space fractured by technology, the world mapped as an integrated
> circuit where everything pulses, rarely lingers, and never quiets. ***It***
> renders intangible or vaporous any sustained presence in place and
> time, leaving to theory or chance a durable connection between two
> people.

Comment: The camera work.

Comment: *the style in which they are shown* before the previous **it**.

Comment: ... **the style** dislocates them from the plastic, sensate world. **It** evokes... **It** renders...

Comment: Probably "the style".